# Mysql - show all results, including 0 results

Tags: mysql, zero

so I have the following tables:

**Article**

> - article_id

**Comment**

> - comment_id
> - article_id

What I want to do is search for all articles despite having or not comments and show the article id and how many comments it has.

Imagine that I have two articles and just the first one has comments. I can't get to make a query that shows me both of them and their comments number.

EDIT 1:

I made the following query after reading the responses and I'm almost there! There is only a problem. Instead of getting 0 when a article has no comments, I get 1.

> SELECT *,COUNT(a.article_id) FROM article as a LEFT JOIN comment as c ON a.article_id = c.article_id GROUP BY a.article_id;

EDIT 2:

A simple mistake. I changed "COUNT(a.article_id)" to "COUNT(C.article_id)". So obvious! :) Thanks for the help people ;)

> SELECT *,COUNT(c.article_id) FROM article as a LEFT JOIN comment as c ON a.article_id = c.article_id GROUP BY a.article_id;

Comment: Use left join. Should work .

Comment: I don't know how to use LEFT JOIN :/ I've already tried using it but I always get some errors... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Article as a INNER JOIN Comment as c ON a.article_id = c.article_id;
```

Comment: I marked this as correct since it is the answer closer to what I wanted :) I just needed to make some changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(COUNT(c.comment_id),0) AS 'Comment Count' , 
    a.article_id 
FROM 
  article a 
LEFT JOIN 
  comment c 
  ON c.article_id
```

What I'm doing here is using MySQL's `LEFT JOIN` to compare the comment table against the article table (our reference). Where there's a match between the `c.article_id` and `a.article_id`, we grab the data.

Comment: Count will never return `NULL`, if no rows found, it will return 0

Answer (score 1):

Try `LEFT JOIN`

```
Select 
article_id, 
count(comment_id)
from 
article a
LEFT JOIN comment c on (a.article_id=c.article_id)
GROUP BY article_id
```